# Прокрутка скролла к блоку и далее по блокам

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка, fullpage

Нашел подобный вариант http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/, только скролл нужен именно по высоте блоков, а не всю страницу как на примере. Как реализовать прокрутку страницы от блока к блоку с остановкой скролла между разделами?

Comment: браузер по дефолту переходит к элементу ид, которого такое же как хэш, например при адресе: `localhost/#anchor` браузер попытается прокрутить содержимое страницы до элемента у которого `id="anchor"`

Comment: да, но это прокручивает сайт когда заходишь, а нужно прокручивать к ид когда начинаешь колесико крутить.

Comment: можно подписаться на _onscroll_ и на нем в зависимости от направления переходить к ближайшему якорю